# What are the files that i can remove and the project will still be working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have made an Android Studio project. I want to know what folders can i remove from the project. And i can still import it without problems.

[image: Project files]

As you can see in the screenshot, the project folder contains all those folders and files.
As example is i can remove the release folder.

Now, i want to know what other folders or files can i remove (.gradle, .idea .....)?

Or i mean what are the files that are not related to the project and just generated by the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, there are generally no useless files. The files that you delete, will be recreated by Android Studio.

You can delete .gradle folder(which contains settings and other files used by gradle to build the project).

Also, app/build, which will be again recreated by Android Studio. And if you want to know what folders/files are generated by IDE, then anything except

- app/src
- app/proguard-rules.pro
- app/libs
- app/build.gradle
- Project level build.gradle

Anything except above files is generated by IDE.

In short, everything in app folder except app/build is user generated. I'd give a few simple tricks to import other people's project without getting boat-load of gradle errors, but StackOverflow forbids to make statements based on personal experience.

Comment: So, i can keep only those files? and the project will still can be imported on Android Studio?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd not recommend you doing that. What I generally do is, I create a new project, copy paste app/src, copy dependencies from both build.gradle files, add any  libraries from app/libs. This avoids all the gazillion errors that I might face because of importing a new project.

Comment: I need this for an apps generator service. So, I don't want that all the generated apps will have the same android studio files (fingerprint), since the clients are different and each one will put his personalized content on the app (Generating layouts). So, i need to make all clients have different apps (To not be considered as spam). And since the code is similar between all apps, i'm trying to do some modifications on this, that's why i want to know what are the files that i can delete and be generated by the compiler each time.

Comment: Okay, so I get it now. So you can safely delete .gradle and .idea folders. (Project settings are stored with each specific project as a set of xml files under the .idea folder)